# What mechanism prevents me from reading /proc/<PID>/environ in containers with a PID namespace shared with the host?

Tags: docker, proc, namespace, kubernetes, capabilities

While investigating sharing the PID namespace with containers, I noticed something interesting that I don't understand. When a container shares the PID namespace with the host, some processes have their environmental variables protected while others do not.

Let's take, for example, mysql. I'll start a container with a env variable set:

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ docker container run -it -d --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret mysql
551b309513926caa9d5eab5748dbee2f562311241f72c4ed5d193c81148729a6
```

I'll start another container which shares the host PID namespace and try to access the `environ` file:

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ docker container run -it --rm --pid host ubuntu /bin/bash

root@1c670d9d7138:/# ps aux | grep mysql
999        18212  5.0  9.6 2006556 386428 pts/0  Ssl+ 17:55   0:00 mysqld
root       18573  0.0  0.0   2884  1288 pts/0    R+   17:55   0:00 grep --color=auto mysql

root@1c670d9d7138:/# cat /proc/18212/environ
cat: /proc/18212/environ: Permission denied
```

Something is blocking my access to read the environmental variables. I was able to find out that I need `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` to read it in a container:

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ docker container run -it --rm --pid host --cap-add SYS_PTRACE  ubuntu /bin/bash

root@079d4c1d66d8:/# cat /proc/18212/environ
MYSQL_PASSWORD=HOSTNAME=551b30951392MYSQL_DATABASE=MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecretPWD=/HOME=/var/lib/mysqlMYSQL_MAJOR=8.0GOSU_VERSION=1.14MYSQL_USER=MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.30-1.el8TERM=xtermSHLVL=0MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binMYSQL_SHELL_VERSION=8.0.30-1.el8
```

However, not all processes are protected in this way.

For example, I'll start another container ubuntu container with a env variable set and run the `tail` command.

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ docker container run --rm --env SUPERSECRET=helloworld -d ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
42023615a4415cd4064392e890622530adee1f42a8a2c9027f4921a522d5e1f2
```

Now when I run the container with the shared pid namespace, I can access the environmental variables.

```
ubuntu@sandbox:~$ docker container run -it --rm --pid host ubuntu /bin/bash

root@3a774156a364:/# ps aux | grep tail
root       19056  0.0  0.0   2236   804 ?        Ss   17:57   0:00 tail -f /dev/null
root       19176  0.0  0.0   2884  1284 pts/0    S+   17:58   0:00 grep --color=auto tail

root@3a774156a364:/# cat /proc/19056/environ
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/binHOSTNAME=42023615a441SUPERSECRET=helloworldHOME=/root
```

What mechanism is preventing me from reading the mysqld environmental variables and not the `tail -f` process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What mechanism is preventing me from reading the mysqld environmental variables and not the tail -f process?

The fact that you're running with a different user ID in the first case. If we start up your two examples:

```
docker run --name mysql -it -d --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret mysql:latest
docker run --name tail -it -d --env MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret ubuntu:latest tail -f /dev/null
```

And then look at the resulting processes:

```
$ ps -fe n |grep -E 'tail|mysqld' | grep -v grep
     999  422026  422005  2 22:50 pts/0    Ssl+   0:00 mysqld
       0  422170  422144  0 22:50 pts/0    Ss+    0:00 tail -f /dev/null
```

We see that `mysqld` is running as UID 999, while the `tail` command is running as UID 0. When we start up a new container in the host pid namespace, we can only read the `environ` for processes that are owned by the same UID and GID. So this works, because by default a container runs with UID 0:

```
$ docker run  --rm --pid host ubuntu:latest cat /proc/422170/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
HOSTNAME=e89c069d4674
TERM=xterm
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret
HOME=/root
```

And this fails:

```
$ docker run  --rm --pid host ubuntu:latest cat /proc/422026/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
cat: /proc/422026/environ: Permission denied
```

We can only read the `environ` file for a process running under a different UID or GID if we have the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability. The logic for this check is in the [`ptrace_may_access` function](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/ptrace.c#L286) in the kernel:

```c
    if (uid_eq(caller_uid, tcred->euid) &&
        uid_eq(caller_uid, tcred->suid) &&
        uid_eq(caller_uid, tcred->uid)  &&
        gid_eq(caller_gid, tcred->egid) &&
        gid_eq(caller_gid, tcred->sgid) &&
        gid_eq(caller_gid, tcred->gid))
        goto ok;
    if (ptrace_has_cap(tcred->user_ns, mode))
        goto ok;
```

We can make that failing example work by having the container run with the same UID and GID as the mysql process:

```
$ docker run -u 999:999 --rm --pid host ubuntu:latest cat /proc/422026/environ | tr '\0' '\n'
MYSQL_PASSWORD=
HOSTNAME=bde980104dcd
MYSQL_DATABASE=
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=SuperSecret
PWD=/
HOME=/var/lib/mysql
MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0
GOSU_VERSION=1.14
MYSQL_USER=
MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.31-1.el8
TERM=xterm
SHLVL=0
MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
MYSQL_SHELL_VERSION=8.0.31-1.el8
```